# Install Cargo/Rust on Ubuntu 18.04 Amazon AMI to use Cargo Packages (Exa)

Tags: 18.04, ssh, aws, rust

I wanted to install and use Exa on AWS Ubuntu 18.04 Image. Exa is a cargo package, how do I install Rust and Cargo to install Exa? How do I use cargo packages on Ubuntu 18.04?

I ran into the error `error: linker`cc`not found" on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` when running `cargo install` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we download our .pem file from the amazon dashboard, run `chmod 400 /mylocation/mypem.pem` to change permissions on it, run

```
ssh -i "mykey.pem" ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

in the directory with our .pem file and we should be in the server.

Next, we run commands

`curl -sSf https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup.sh | sh`

[from here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/getting-started/installation.html) to install rust and cargo. These are needed to run cargo packages. After that we can install our desired cargo package [exa](https://github.com/ogham/exa) with

`cargo install exa`.

Here I ran into an error error: `linker`cc`not found" on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`. This is because we don't have gcc in the amazon ubuntu 18.04 ami. we need to run `sudo apt install gcc`, `sudo apt install g++`, and `sudo apt install cmake` but will also run into an error because we don't have the updated repos (since 10/10). This means we need to run `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`, and when it asks us if we want to upgrade, we want to upgrade to the maintainer (Ubuntu's) rather than keep Amazon's, then install gcc, g++, and cmake.

Finally, we'll get a warning:

```
warning: be sure to add `/home/ubuntu/.cargo/bin` to your PATH to be able to run the installed binaries
```

So we add it by adding `export PATH="/home/ubuntu/.cargo/bin:$PATH"` or more generally, 
`export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` to our .[bashrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384075/what-is-bashrc-how-to-find-the-startup-file-putty) file and run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to reload our bashrc file.

This should also work for installing other cargo packages. Have fun with Rust in AWS!